# MFMailComposeViewController translucency does not work

Tags: objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

The MFMailComposeViewController translucency property does not work.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailView.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

[self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work because it is a seperate app thats shown and not really a local view.

Apple uses the concept of Remote VCs that appear to be in your app but are infact own 'apps':

http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/